# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzk.class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

this is the error and I can´t find the duplicate entry.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzk.class

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.john.mapafinal"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

Help please!

Comment: Use consistent versions of Google and Firebase libraries. `firebase-auth:9.0.2` probably won't work with 8.4.0 of play-services libs.  Consider upgrading all of them to current version: 9.6.1.

Comment: Also, `firebase-client-android:2.3.1` is the legacy API.  It cannot be used in the same build with libraries for the new 9.x API: `firebase-auth:9.0.2`.  See the [Firebase Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: @qbix This works, thanks